# XAML Data Binding value not refreshing inside two ContentPages

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding

I am trying to output a value from my object to two different entries. Both entries are on the same view but in different ContentPages as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="myApp.Views.ViewTabs.ViewHome"
            xmlns:localTabs="clr-namespace:myApp.Views.ViewTabs"
            xmlns:localObjPages="clr-namespace:myApp.Objects"
            >

    <ContentPage Title="PageOne">
        <ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <localObjPages:PagesObj/>
        </ContentPage.BindingContext>
        
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Entry 
                x:Name="EntryOne" Text="{Binding BananaCount}"/>
                <Entry 
                x:Name="EntryTwo" Text="{Binding BananaCount}"/>                  
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage>

<ContentPage Title="PageTwo">
        <ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <localObjPages:PagesObj/>
        </ContentPage.BindingContext>
        
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Entry 
                x:Name="EntryThree" Text="{Binding BananaCount}"/>                  
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

My Model:

```
public string BananaCount
        {
            get { return _bananaCount; }
            set
            {
                if (_bananaCount != value)
                {
                    _bananaCount = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("BananaCount");
                }
            }
        }
```

The object is updated and returned in EntryOne or in EntryTwo when I change it either in EntryOne or in EntryTwo. **However, it is not updated in EntryThree.** Why is this? Am I Binding this correctly? Thank you.

Comment: PageTwo is using it's own copy of the bindingcontext, it does not share the same instance with the other page

Comment: Thanks @Jason. Apparently I am new to programming. What would you recommend to do?

Comment: if you want all pages to use the same instance of the BindingContext, you could specify it at the TabbedPage level instead

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with 
<TabbedPage.BindingContext>
                    <localObjPages:PagesObj/>
    </TabbedPage.BindingContext>
 but it won't show me the objects in subfolders and its properties. Somethings wrong :/

Comment: there is not enough information in your post to make any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

> The object is updated and returned in EntryOne or in EntryTwo when I change it either in EntryOne or in EntryTwo. However, it is not updated in EntryThree. Why is this? Am I Binding this correctly?

Do one sample about TabbedPage, assign datasource for TabbedPage, not contentpage, that you can take a look:

```
<TabbedPage
x:Class="FormsSample.tabbedpage.TabbedPage6"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormsSample.tabbedpage">

  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->  
<ContentPage Title="PageOne">

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="EntryOne" Text="{Binding str}" />
            <Entry x:Name="EntryTwo" Text="{Binding str}" />
            <Button
                x:Name="btn1"
                Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
                Text="change data" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

<ContentPage Title="PageTwo">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="EntryThree" Text="{Binding str}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

```
 public partial class TabbedPage6 : TabbedPage
{
   public tabclass tabc { get; set; }
    public TabbedPage6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabc = new tabclass();
        this.BindingContext = tabc;
    }

    private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabc.str = "this is test!";
    }
}
public class tabclass:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _str;
    public string str
    { 
        get { return _str; } 
        set
        {
            _str = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("str");
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel is one class that implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```